# Navigation container disappears after splash screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I implemented a splash screen last night and this morning I noticed it was taking away my bottom tab navigator. I recreated the problem [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/30cbce)

In the snack, originally you will see the bottom tab navigator. If you go into App.js and uncomment the call to the splashscreen, you will see what I am talking about.

Does anyone know how I could go about making sure this does not happen?
The splash screen is a little extra in itself so if you guys think it would be best to scratch this one and go for something else I am open to suggestions!

Thank you for anything, I appreciate it more than you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are not seeing the Bottom Tab is because you are not rendering that part of the app anymore. You were simply rendering the `<Home/>` component inside the `SplashScreen`, which is not really the bottom tab screen, but a screen that is part of the whole bottom tab.

To make it work, You can do the following,

inside `App.js`, export your `MyTabs` function.

```js
export function MyTabs() {
 // all the previous stuff
}
```

Then import it inside `SplashScreen` like below,

```js
import {MyTabs} from '../App'
```

Now replace `<Home></Home>` with `<MyTabs/>`.

Here's the [Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@nithinpp69/splash-animation)

Not totally sure if this is a good practice, will have to dig up some docs, But will work for your use case.

Comment: Were you able to implement that into the example and get it to work? I get an error when doing that about a nested navigation container.

Comment: Yes, I've posted the snack link above.  https://snack.expo.dev/@nithinpp69/splash-animation. I'll check one more time

Comment: I did checked again, seems like it's working. Can you please share the error you are facing?.

Comment: Hmm so weird. Yours works. What is the difference between yours and this one? Mine will not render. https://snack.expo.dev/@priedejm/30cbce 

For some reason I get the error "Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitly. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them."

Comment: I get a different error when adding the brackets around MyTabs in the import as well

Comment: I got it. The function MyTabs was not being exported in mine. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: Cool. Now to clarify on your previous comment `I get a different error when adding the brackets around MyTabs in the import as well`.  We need to import it inside the brackets because the function `MyTabs` is not a default export from `App.js`. If you do the import without the brackets, it will import the default item from `App.js`, which in our case the function `App()`.

Comment: One more thing, since you tried the import without the brackets, it imported the `App()` which has the `<NavigationContainer/>`. Now the error above makes sense coz now you are rendering the whole `App.js` again.  Which is why the error about nested navigation container.  :)